# Gitlab vs. Github vs. Atlassian

Tags: cloud-service, git, wiki, issue-tracker, continuous-integration

I'm looking for a tools stack for a cloud and mobile development team in a startup. While having worked with Atlassian for a while, I wonder whether Gitlab or Github would be better alternatives.

The tools stack should support:

- git + gitflow
- issue tracking / issue boards / epics / roadmaps
- wiki for mainly for development, but ideally also suitable for Sales/Marketing
- CI/CD for cloud applications with docker/kubernetes
- CI for mobile applications
- cloud-based (with minimal maintenance efforts)

Next to the capabilities, the pricing is also a topic. We're a small team of < 10 people and ramping up slowly. I'm not really keen on spending 99$/month/developer for the setup.

So far I mainly found comparisons on individual aspects of this stack but not the whole lot. Any input or pointer is appreciated.

Comment: re "*keen*"; what budget?

Comment: Sry, question is meanwhile outdated. Went for a mix of Gitlab with Jira in the end. Will close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question. Didn’t find a satisfying solution. The whole git/CICD topic I solved/saw solved in many projects using Gitlab or GitHub. Their issue tracking / wiki parts weren’t as satisfying, which resulted in choosing other tools and going for add ons, e.g. with Jira, confluence, YouTrack, notion. The integrations where pretty decent for all of these, so we didn’t have to „settle“ with gitlab‘s/GitHub’s built-in tracking or wiki.